# sorting an array of structures by 2 parameters

Tags: c, struct, qsort

I have a structure

```
struct employee {
    int record;
    int ID;
....
};

employee * arr = (employee*) malloc(501 * sizeof (employee));
```

And i need to sort it by this two parameters (ID at first and record as the second).
I'm using standart Qsort with

```
 qsort (employee, records, sizeof(employee), compare);
```

But i dont know, how to edit basic compare function, to make it works

I have samething like this

```
int comparestruct(const employee *p1, const employee *p2)
{
    const struct employee *elem1 = p1;    
    const struct employee *elem2 = p2;

   if ( elem1->ID < elem2->ID)
      return -1;
   else if (elem1->ID > elem2->ID)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}
```

But this isn't working...

Any help please?

Comment: How could it possibly work if you don't even mention the `record` field? (And what is `zam`? Should be `void`.)

Comment: typecast p1 and p2 to employee? not sure if there is some kind of inheritance there or how zam relates to an employee

Comment: zam means employee, i translated it to english and forget this..

Comment: Why are you passing employee (struct name) in the qSort like qSort(employee, ...? it should be passed an instance of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way would be something like:

```
int comparestruct(const void *a_, const void *b_) {
    const struct employee *a = a_;
    const struct employee *b = b_;
    int rv = a->ID - b->ID;
    if (rv == 0) rv = a->record - b->record;
    return rv;
}
```

Of course, this has a subtle bug if the subtractions might overflow (which depends on the range of your IDs and record numbers.)  If that is a possible problem, you might need:

```
int comparestruct(const void *a_, const void *b_) {
    const struct employee *a = a_;
    const struct employee *b = b_;
    if (a->ID < b->ID) return -1;
    if (a->ID > b->ID) return 1;
    if (a->record < b->record) return -1;
    if (a->record > b->record) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

instead